# Joomla html slow page load time (not js, images, css)

Tags: performance, joomla, latency

The load time for the **base html** of any page on my **Joomla** website (removed) is ~2seconds.

- There aren't an excessive number of modules (even the pages with virtually no content take ~2seconds to load: (removed)
- There aren't too many articles (or anything else that would make any db queries overly strenuous)
- Loading a tiny file takes <10ms (robots.txt or images)
- The file sizes of the base html pages are in the 30-40kb range

What is causing the slowdown in loading the initial html page? How can I figure out what is causing the slowdown (and fix it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on debugging in global configuration and see if it shows you any slow queries.

Comment: How do I identify a slow query from a normal one?

I turned on debugging temporarily, copied the queries executed, and ran them individually in a command line prompt (~40 queries, ~20 unique). The run time of each query was < 0.00seconds. Some queries did generate a great deal text (as in, took 2-5seconds to print out in the command prompt). Thanks for your response.

Comment: Well you do what you did, which means that the issue isn't the queries most likely.

Comment: In the debugging  did you look a the profiling information? That will tell you how long each event takes. I'm not sure why you are using robots.txt as a base, it has none of the things that would make page load slow.

Comment: Profile Information:
Application 0.018 seconds (+0.018); 0.41 MB (+0.414) - afterLoad ||
Application 1.777 seconds (+1.760); 4.16 MB (+3.750) -afterInitialise ||
Application 1.804 seconds (+0.026); 4.77 MB (+0.602) - afterRoute ||
Application 2.289 seconds (+0.485); 5.96 MB (+1.188) - afterDispatch...
Memory Usage: 10.28 MB (10,778,848 Bytes)

robots.txt was to show that the problem isn't network latency. From the profile information, ~0.5s was spend on transferring data and ~1.8s was spent doing *something* (before the images, css, and other content began loading).

Comment: From your help, that *something* doesn't seem to be the execution of queries. What else can it be? Are there any tools that can help find out? Thanks again for your response.

Comment: So the question is what is going on afterInitialize. Are you using the core here or extensions? Also are you using an sef extension?

Comment: Good call. I'm using RocketTheme and had disabled the RokBooster extension when enabling another caching extension. I re-enabled RokBooster and the initial html load time dropped ~0.5s. It also automatically enabled GZip and some js optimization which cut the progressive load time in half. I'm only using 2-3 small extensions apart from the core Joomla+RocketTheme (no sef extensions), so the loading time is likely due to the large, unoptimized template and hosting limitations among other little niggling things. It's acceptably fast now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are many tools you can use in order to check it, I'll present a few of them:

- http://www.webpagetest.org
- http://tools.pingdom.com (shows that the size of the page is **3.6MB**!!!)
- [*YSlow*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/) (plugin for *Firefox*)
- [*PageSpeed*](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) (plugin for both *Chrome* & *FF*)

Using the analysis that the first tool provides, you'll see that that the main reasons for your website's slowness are:

1. You don't have [compression enabled](http://www.mydigitallife.info/configure-and-enable-gzip-compression-with-mod_deflate-to-speed-up-apache-and-save-bandwidth/) (can be configured under `httpd.conf` and `.htaccess`)
2. You don't take advantage of browser caching (can be configured both in the files I mentioned above as well as in Joomla plugins).
3. Your images are not optimized, meaning, you take large images (large in KB size) and display them in lower dimensions.

Fix these three issues and your website will load much faster!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I realize those problems are there and very fixable. My real issue is with Joomla: that it takes 2+ seconds to respond to any page request, while it takes <10ms to hit bearingpointcareers.ie/robots.txt. Everything else load progressively after that, so it's not as big a deal.